# Matching a TemplateField to a GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I have created a template field which provides a bulletted list. the list is dynamically populated from a SQL database table.  The problem is, when the Gridview populates it takes all rows from the database and fills all rows in the grid.

How do I make the template field correspond to the correct row in the gridview? I would appreciate any suggestions!

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Features">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="Server" DataSourceID="bltDescriptionSource">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li class=roomBullets><%# Eval("roomCount")%></li>
                            <li class=seasonBullets><%# Eval("seasonPeriod") %></li>
                            <li class=bullets><%# Eval("Feature1") %></li>
                            <li class=bullets><%# Eval("Feature2") %></li>
                            <li class=bullets><%# Eval("Feature3") %></li>
                            <li class=telBullets><%# Eval("telnumber") %></li>
                            <li class=emailBullets><%# Eval("emailAddress") %></li>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the repeater?

Comment: Hi Humpy. Yes, I have tried it with a DataList too.

Comment: Instead of using list items, use ASP:Labels. I know you can put as many as you want in column. I have done that way before. Basically what it looks like you are doing is having all those li in a single column. You can even use <div> for spacing and things like that.